# PHP - Sort json array descending order

Tags: php, json

I am trying to set my json array from descending to ascending to show newest values at the top.
I want to sort by the Date element inside the array.

This piece of code is ordering it ascending to descending, showing oldest at the top:

```
function sortDate($a, $b) {
     return strtotime($a['Date']) - strtotime($b['Date']);
}

usort($jsonDecodedGets, 'sortDate');
```

Is there a way to do this but arrange descending to ascending?

Comment: `strtotime($b['Date']) - strtotime($a['Date'])`

Comment: @RocketHazmat Wow was that simple haha. Thank you! Worked.

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad I could help :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply reverse the sort function so that you are doing `b-a` instead of `a-b`.

```
function sortDate($a, $b) {
    return strtotime($b['Date']) - strtotime($a['Date']);
}
```